# Convert long Timestamp to shorter Timestamp

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have a Timestamp in this format: 1479912701805

If you check on 
http://www.epochconverter.com/ you can see that date is

```
GMT: Wed, 23 Nov 2016 14:51:41.805 GMT
```

Now I need to shorten that long to 
1479859200 which is 3 number shorter, I guess milisecs

Comment: Your second number isn't *just* three digits shorter; it's a different point in time. Specifically, it is midnight (`GMT: Wed, 23 Nov 2016 00:00:00 GMT`) of the date in which your first timestamp fell. Is this intentional? Are you asking how to get the timestamp for midnight, or are you just asking how to divide by 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your data in example, you need to remove hours, minute and seconds from 
the value first. Using the `%` will be enough.

Remove the remainder of the number of milliseconds of a day from this value.

```
    l -= l% (1000*60*60*24);
```

A small example :

```
    long l = 1479912701805l;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(l);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
    l -= l% (1000*60*60*24);
    c.setTimeInMillis(l);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

> Wed Nov 23 15:51:41 CET 2016
>
> Wed Nov 23 01:00:00 CET 2016

PS : The remaining hours is the time zone ;)

> 1479912701805
>
> 1479859200000

Then, just divide this by 1000 to remove the 3 first digit

Answer (score 1):

divide by 1000 to get secs? linked site is recognizing "long" (milisecs) timestamps and shows: **Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds**, then calculates after /1000 division, so both 1479859200 and 1479859200000 are same date on this site

note that your examples are 1479912701805 and 1479859200 - same date only, but not hour/min/secs. if you divide "long" one /1000 you won't get second one

there is also method:

```
long timeMillis = 1479859200000;
long timeSecs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeMillis);
```

which is of course dividing by 1000, but you may find other `TimeUnit` methods useful